# Only part of the object is being scaled

Tags: scale

I'm trying to shrink a specific section of my design, which originally, I made like this:

[image]

When I use the shrink tool, I get this:

[image]

But from what I can tell when I open [CURA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cura_(software)), it's almost like I'm shrinking the inside and not the entire stem of the object? It looks like there's still an outside layer of the stem that isn't being shrunk, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: It looks like you don't have all of the vertices in the stem of the glass selected. You may have "Limit Selection to Visible" turned on.

Comment: Doesn't look like the "limit selection to visible" box is checked, from what I can tell.

Comment: It looks like you don't have all of the vertices in the stem of the glass selected.

Comment: Disable "limit selection to visible"(https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrHjR.png) or switch to wireframe view when selecting the vertices you want to affect. I suggest that you read this page in the manual: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/selecting/introduction.html?highlight=limit%20selection%20visible

Comment: Did you really have to resort to CURA to see that you had (selected and thus) scaled only a part of the intended vertices...?!? it seems quite evident in the picture...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out int he comments above, you don't have the entire stem of the glass selected. To select it all, press <kbd>Z</kbd> to enable wireframe view. This will let you select through the mesh as well, not just what you can see. Then use the box select tool with <kbd>B</kbd> to select everything you want. Change back to solid view again with <kbd>Z</kbd> and the scaling will work as you expected.